# Why Android Studio show Code xml like " � � "

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, apk

I opened an apk application and wanted to modify the xml file ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJGeL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources in APKs are compiled. They're binary XML and not plaintext. If you want to edit the resources of an APK, you should look into using [APKTool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/).